# remove time from DateTime in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have these questions

1. How do I remove time from datetime (01/01/2017 instead of 01/01/2017 00:00:00)
2. How do I display on year (2017 instead of 01/01/2017 00:00:00)

See the view below

```
                <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PAYMENT_YEAR)
            </td>
```

PAYMENT_YEAR is DateTime in the database. I want to do it from view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `ToShortDateString()` method on the `DateTime` object. This will give you the short date string representation from that DateTime value.

```
<td>item.PAYMENT_YEAR.ToShortDateString()</td>
```

If you want just the year, you may access the `Year` property.

```
<td>item.PAYMENT_YEAR.Year</td>
```

You can use the `Year` property with the `Html.DisplayFor` helper method

```
<p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.PAYMENT_YEAR.Year)</p>
```

But you cannot make a method call inside `DisplayFor`. So you may just go with

```
<td>item.PAYMENT_YEAR.ToShortDateString()</td>
```

If the type of `PAYMENT_YEAR` property nullable DateTime (`DateTime`),  you need to do a null check before calling the helper method

```
if (item.PAYMENT_YEAR.HasValue)
{
    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PAYMENT_YEAR.Value.Year)</span>
}
```

Or you can simply print the value without using the helper method along with [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

```
<td>item.PAYMENT_YEAR?.Year</td>
```

Comment: '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PAYMENT_YEAR.Value.Year)' gives this error   **Nullable object must have a value**

Comment: What is the type of `PAYMENT_YEAR` property ?

Comment: PAYMENT_YEAR property is datetime

Comment: if it is `DateTime`, why are you using `.Value` property ? It should be `DateTime?`

Comment: See the updated answer which handles null values as well

Comment: While I tried to display just the year only, it worked. However, when I tried to display date and remove time using this  '@{
            if (item.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION.HasValue)
            {
                item.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION.Value.ToShortDateString();
            }
                    }'   its not working